# Compat macro to convert a row matrix to a vector?

Tags: julia

In Julia 0.4 indexing one row of a matrix returns a matrix, e.g.,

`julia> ones(2,2)[1,:]
1x2 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  1.0`

But in Julia 0.5 (nightly), the same command returns a vector:

`julia> ones(2,2)[1,:]
2-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.0
 1.0`

Is there a macro in Compat.jl that makes Julia 0.4 return a vector too? If not, what's the best way to write code for this case that works with both versions of Julia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either write `vec(ones(2,2)[1,:])` which will be a vector in both 0.4 and 0.5 or `ones(2,2)[1:1,:]` which will be an `1xn` matrix in both 0.4 and 0.5.